# Change variable horizontally in excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to change a variable in an excel formula horizontally and maintain one variable constant.

`O3/$C18, P3/$C18, Q3/$C18`

I can keep the the bottom variable constant by using the $ symbol but when I want to extend the formula to additional cells, the top variable does not change horizontally, rather vertically.

Thank you for your help. Cheers

Comment: *Bottom not bottle...

Answer (score 3):

The dollar signs in excel "fix" the item to their right

$C18

means C will always be fixed, and 18 can change

C$18 means C can change, but 18 is always fixed.

$C$18 means C is fixed and 18 is fixed (ie always use C18 no matter what direction you drag the cell)

I dont fully understand what you want to do but hopefully the above will help

based on the comments below i think i understand what you mean

try a formula like this

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,ROW()))/$C$18
```

here `address` takes the row and column, so row = 1 and column = which ever row you are on (so row1 = A, row2=B etc)

then indirect lets you use that as a reference point

Hope that works

Comment: Thank you for the help on the bottom variable. For the top, when I want to copy the formula into another cell, want the top variable to change to the next cell horizontally, i.e. A3 to B3 to C3 and so on. Instead when I copy the formula to another cell it changes the top variable from A3 to A4 to A5 or vertically.

Comment: I'm trying to understand.  When you say "copy the formula", do you mean copy it down? i.e. if the formula is in A1, then copy it down to A2?

Comment: So if in A1 I have the formula "B1/$C$18" and when I copy that formula into A2, A3, and A4 excel will give me "B2/$C$18, B3/$C$18, B4/$C$18". I want Excel to give me "C1/$C$18, D1/$C$18, E1/$C$18". So changing the top variable horizontally instead of vertically. Sorry for the confusion, thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to copy your formula vertically, but have the columns update as if you were copying horizontally. For example, you want to copy `=O3` to the cell below it as `=P3`.

For the top, consider the `Offset()` and `Row()` functions. Let's say that Cells A1,B1,C1 are `1`,`2`, and `3`. Try `=OFFSET($A$1,0,ROW()-1)`. If you copy that formula vertically, the result will be 1, then 2, then 3.

So in your case, try `=OFFSET($O$3,0,ROW()-1)`. It probably needs a little adjustment.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do this:

Start with the formula in this form:

```
=O$3/$P$18
```

Copy and paste it across so that you get:

```
=O$3/$P$18   =P$3/$P$18   =Q$3/$P$18
```

Copy the two formulas you pasted and select the cell below the first formula.

Then do a `Paste Special` / `Transpose`, which can be accessed by right-clicking the selected cell (that is, the one below the first formula that you entered) and then choosing the button that shows a little two-cell range flat and then upright.

[image: Context menu show transpose button]

Finish up by deleting the formulas in the cells you just copied from.

[image: Worksheet cells with formulas]